# bash sort on column but do not sort same columns

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

My file contains:

```
9827259163,0,D<br>
9827961481,0,D<br>
9827202228,0,A<br>
9827529897,5,D<br>
9827529897,0#1#5#8,A<br>
9827700249,0#1,A<br>
9827700249,1#2,D<br>
9883219029,0,A<br>
9861065312,0,A<br>
```

I want it to sort on the basis of first column, if the records in first column are same, then do not sort those records further.

`$ sort -t, -k1,1 test`
  `9827202228,0,A`
  `9827259163,0,D`
**`9827529897,0#1#5#8,A`**
**`9827529897,5,D`**
  `9827700249,0#1,A`
  `9827700249,1#2,D`
  `9827961481,0,D`
  `9861065312,0,A`
  `9883219029,0,A`

but what I expect is:

`9827202228,0,A`
  `9827259163,0,D`
**`9827529897,5,D`**
**`9827529897,0#1#5#8,A`**
  `9827700249,0#1,A`
  `9827700249,1#2,D`
  `9827961481,0,D`
  `9861065312,0,A`
  `9883219029,0,A`

because there are two records for `9827529897` and `9827700249`, therefore it should not be sorted further.

Please suggest the command in bash shell

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add option `-s`

```
 sort -st, -k1,1 test
```

output:

```
9827202228,0,A
9827259163,0,D
9827529897,5,D
9827529897,0#1#5#8,A
9827700249,0#1,A
9827700249,1#2,D
9827961481,0,D
9861065312,0,A
9883219029,0,A
```